# Does restoring earlier version of Google Spreadsheet also restore earlier versions of the script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have been modifying multiple scripts after making substantial changes to a spreadsheet.  Initially the changes would have affected the functionality of the scripts.  After consulting with the spreadsheet manager, we determined not to make any changes to the spreadsheet that would affect the functionality of the scripts.  However, there are some major changes to the spreadsheet that we want to keep in place.

Rather than pouring through long scripts to modify them again, can I simply restore an earlier version of the spreadsheet and make a copy of that spreadsheet, then, now that I have a copy of the original, restore the spreadsheet back to the spreadsheet that has the changes we want to keep in place?

Now I would have a copy of the original and  I would have the current spreadsheet.  Will the scripts in the copy of the original be the original scripts?  If that is the case, I can simply copy those original scripts and paste them into the current spreadsheet, overwriting the recent changes I have made.

Hope this all makes sense.  The long and short of it is, "does restoring an earlier version of Google sheets also restore earlier versions of the scripts associated with the spreadsheet?

Comment: About `does restoring an earlier version of Google sheets also restore earlier versions of the scripts associated with the spreadsheet?`, it's no. In the current stage, I think that even when the revision of Google Spreadsheet is changed to older, the script of the container-bound script is not changed to the older version.

Comment: Hmm...is there a way to access earlier versions of a script?

Comment: Thank you for replying.. When you want to use the history of Google Apps Script project, is this post useful? https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/08/apps-script-project-history.html If you want to achieve this using a script, this post might be useful. https://medium.com/google-cloud/managing-history-of-google-apps-script-50434541038f

Comment: Thanks @Tainake.  You are very helpful.  Unfortunately, my project history shows only today.  Is this because I did not deploy them in the first place?  I have never used the "Deploy" feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, spreadsheet versioning is independent of scripts. When you restore a version of the spreadsheet, the script will not change.

Recently Google added versioning to scripts: section Project History. However, it requires you to manually deploy the script to save a version of the code created. Official [announcement](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/08/apps-script-project-history.html) and [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions), post on [how to work with the Project History](https://medium.com/google-cloud/managing-history-of-google-apps-script-50434541038f) (thanks to @Tanaike for the links).

Alternatively, you can use official command-line tool `clasp` ([GitHub](https://github.com/google/clasp), [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp)) to version scripts yourself. As an added bonus, you can use your local editor and other tools when developing Apps Script.

Comment: Does Google have any documentation on this?

Comment: @Codedabbler If you mean the Project History, then @Tanaike left two links in the comments to the question.  As to the `clasp`, here is the official page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp and more data is in the clasp repository.  I have updated the answer with all the links.

Comment: Thanks.  No, actually I mean, does Google documentation cover Revision history in regard to scripts?  I couldn't find any (maybe due to the wrong keywords), but it is helpful to have the source so I can review it and understand all the implications of re-working a spreadsheet with attached script.

Comment: @Codedabbler Project history functionality is pretty new.  This is the only documentation page I am aware of: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions , although it is pretty much the same as the official announcement.  In a nutshell, it allows you to compare different versions and restore one of them; no other effects I am aware of.  As to the spreadsheet-script connection, there is virtually none: these are two independent entities that are connected only functionally: script can pull data from the sheet and sheet use formulas from the script.

Comment: Thank you.  I was under the impression that if it is a container-bound script, then it would be attached to the revision history of the spreadsheet itself.  Guess not.  Seems like Google should note this in their documentation.  Thank you for all the information you shared.